# MS Word - using a date variable without macros

Tags: ms-word, word-2016

I want to create a Word template which will:

a) prompt user for a date

b) display that date

c) calculate other dates from that date.

I'm using MS Word 2016.

I've never done anything like this in Word but after doing a bit of research I see that there are advanced options in Word which maybe I could use for that. I don't want to use macros for this as I'm thinking that if I can make this work, then I would share this template with the rest of the company and I don't want them to enable macros (we have enough security concerns without that).

I've tried to use a FILLIN field to prompt user for a date. This works, however,  I would like this field to be a variable which I can reference later in the document. I haven't found a way to do that with my FILLIN field. Is it possible?

I've seen others mention DocProperties but I'm having a hard time making it work.

For example, if I go to Quick Parts -> Document Property, none of the options are for a custom date. Is there a way to add your own?
And if I go to Quick Parts -> Fields, I see Date, CreateDate, SaveDate which insert "today's date" - not what I want. Again, how do I add my own Field?

I could do this in many ways by using Excel but I wanted to see if I can make it happen with Word. I hope you guys will have an idea.

Comment: The only way you can do the things you want to do is via a macro. Word doesn't have any built in support for asking the user for input or doing calculations other than doing it in VBA - extending Word's functionality is exactly why VBA exists.